# Music Server for WLAN-Speakers

Tags: audio, hardware, music

There are several systems with WLAN-Speakers for sale. Most of them consist of several Boxes with WLAN-Recievers and a WLAN-Router/Storage-Device to spread the 
sound information. The WLAN-Speakers usually cost more than normal speakers with the same quality. That's oke, but I do not intend to buy a expensive router for 
around 300 €. I would prefer to so a music server on a usual computer like moc or 
anything comparable because that much more flexible with the hardware and software issues. The WLAN-Speaker systems are usually not that well documented and sold as "Black boxes".

Is it possible to stream music via my normal WLAN-Router with a Music Server and for the Speakers to play the music? Are there "open" speakers systems on the market? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Please describe your required setup in some more detail.

Comment: I am not actually sure anymore what I wanted. I think I wanted to set up my own Linux Server based music streaming service to be broadcast over the home WiFi. I just saw it as still being open. Also since 2011 the wireless speaker/stream technology took huge strides especially in usability and prices. The question is now definitively irrelevant to me and I guess to anybody else, too.